# How do I use windows controls at the class level?

Tags: c#, class

I have several NumericUpDowns(aka SpinButtons), named hrsMnu, minMnu, secMnu, msMnu. I'm calling a function that takes their Value properties as parameters. I am calling the function at the class level. But, the compiler gives me an error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property, CountdownTimer.Form1.hrsMnu

I need to call the function at the class level. Here is my code:

```
    int hours = Convert.ToInt16(hrsMnu.Value);
    int mins = Convert.ToInt16(minMnu.Value);
    int secs = Convert.ToInt16(secMnu.Value);
    int mss = Convert.ToInt16(msMnu.Value);
    int ms = ToMs(hours, mins, secs, mss);//function I am calling
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hours = Convert.ToInt16(hrsMnu.Value);
        int mins = Convert.ToInt16(minMnu.Value);
        int secs = Convert.ToInt16(secMnu.Value);
        int mss = Convert.ToInt16(msMnu.Value);
        if (ms == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Time is up!");
            return;
        }
        ms--;
    }
    private int ToMs(int hrs, int mins, int secs, int ms)
    {
        int fmins = hrs * 60 + mins;
        int fsecs = fmins * 60 + secs;
        return fsecs * 1000 + ms;
    }
```

Note: I am making a timer application. This is the main code.

Comment: You hope that xxxMru has a value *before* the user starts using your class.  Idle hope, it has to be displayed first and then the user has to think and click for a while to figure out what the proper value should be.  And *then* clicks the OK button.  The exception message is just telling you that you are getting the order of events wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add fields to the form class for this.  Just do:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int hours = Convert.ToInt16(hrsMnu.Value);
    int mins = Convert.ToInt16(minMnu.Value);
    int secs = Convert.ToInt16(secMnu.Value);
    int mss = Convert.ToInt16(msMnu.Value);
    int ms = ToMs(hours, mins, secs, mss);//function I am calling
    if (ms == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    ms--;
}
private int ToMs(int hrs, int mins, int secs, int ms)
{
    int fmins = hrs * 60 + mins;
    int fsecs = fmins * 60 + secs;
    return fsecs * 1000 + ms;
}
```

Although I don't see what the point is since you don't *do* anything with `ms` after you calculate it.

Comment: I've tried this before. The problem is that the ms variable will become, for example, 1000. It will decrement at the end, so it will be 999. Then, the tick function invokes again (somehow), and the ms variable will become 100. I do not want this.

Comment: What I want:
The interval property for my timer is 1 ms. The user enters numbers into various SpinButtons. We call the `ToMs()` function with the value  of each spinbutton as parameters. Since the Tick handler is actually being called several times, every time before it is called(at the end of the function), we decrement the ms variable. When it reaches 0, we display a MessageBox("Time is Up!").

Comment: Are you saying you are able to change the timer in the spinbuttons while the timer is running?  You should only be looking at the values once to capture them then start the timer.

Comment: @EdwardKarak I would make `ms` a class property, set it's value wen you click the button to start the timer, and decrement it in `Timer_Tick`.